# Eloquent OneToMany Relationships challenge

Tags: php, eloquent, lumen

I'm building an application using `Lumen 5.8` and have a very simple model as follow:

```php
class Party extends Model {

    protected $table = 'party';

    public function campaigns(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Campaign');
    }

}
```

---

```php
class Campaign extends Model {

    protected $table = 'campaign';

    public function party(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Party');
    }

}
```

And my tables are defined as follow:

```
party (id,name)

campaign (id,name,party_id)
```

When I use the find method on Campaign or Party it returns the right rows. However if I try to use the relationship and get all campaigns a party has it never returns a row.

I tried the following code:

```php
$campaings = Party::find($id)->campaigns();
```

and result is empty! But if I use the following I can get all campaigns:

```php
$campaings = Campaign::where('party_id' , $id)->get();
```

What is that I'm not doing right?

Thanks

Comment: You have to execute the query: `$campaings = Party::find($id)->campaigns;` or `$campaings = Party::find($id)->campaigns()->get();`

Comment: Wow! I was missing the ->get() call! now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To get the campaings rows, you need to add the `->get()` to the end of your query:

```php
Party::find($id)->campaigns()->get();
```

Or

```php
Party::find($id)->campaigns;
```